# Group combination with optimization

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to create 5 sub groups with 5 people in each, the groups have to be based on the overall optimization of those groups.

Data set

- Person A   7  2   6   4   5
- Person B   5  1   1   3   1
- Person C   2  1   1   3   2
- Person D   2  1   1   3   1
- Person E   1  1   2   3   1
- Person F   3  1   1   2   2
- Person G   3  1   1   2   2
- Person H   3  1   2   2   1
- Person I   2  2   1   2   2
- Person J   2  1   3   2   2
- Person K   2  3   2   2   1
- Person L   2  2   1   2   1
- Person M   2  2   2   2   1
- Person N   2  1   2   2   1
- Person O   1  2   1   2   5
- Person P   1  2   2   2   2
- Person Q   1  5   1   2   1
- Person R   1  1   2   2   1
- Person S   2  2   1   1   3
- Person T   2  3   1   1   2
- Person U   2  2   1   1   2
- Person V   2  2   1   1   2
- Person W   1  2   2   1   2
- Person X   1  2   2   1   2
- Person Y   1  3   2   1   1
- Person Z   1  2   2   1   1

However I am very unsure how to tackle the problem, does anyone have any ideas as to where to start with tackling this issue ?

Comment: overall optimisation of **what**, precisely? Also, 5 groups of 5 people, but you listed 26 people...

Comment: That was to indicate that not everyone needed to be selected into groups.
The optimization of their scores, which is represented by the 5 values (which goes from 1 to 10), I'm trying to make the overall strength of the sub groups as strong as possible. Without ending up in a situation where one group is very weak

Comment: Optimisation of scores in what way? The sum? The maximum? The average? The product? I mean, you are not providing any context here. For example, is a group where all people have scores of $5$ better or worse than on where $2$ people have scores of $10$ and three have a score of $2$? You **need** to provide context, because at the moment, your questio is **not** self-contained.

Comment: It would have to be the overall sum of the combined values of all the people in each of the sub groups

Comment: That still leaves you with $5$ numbers, one for each subgroup. So, is the result $(20,20,25, 60, 100)$ better or worse than $(50,50,50,50,50)$?

Comment: I would say that the (50,50,50,50,50) would be better than the (20,20,25,60,100) as the overall sum of the first one is 250 where the second one is 225

Comment: So you are simply summing the scores of all groups? In that case, all groupings will have the same score. I hope you understand I am not mocking you, I am just demonstrating how your question is impossible to answer because it's not well defined.

Comment: I don't take it as mocking as you are right it wasn't well defined. However I'm still looking for how to do the optimization/combination of the groups when looking at the sums of each group as a determining factor

Comment: But if you look at the sum of each group, then sum these sums, then you will get the same result no matter how you group $25$ people into $5$ groups. That's my point.